# Inject Javascript into Scala Html Renderer

Tags: javascript, scala, apache-spark

I have a (working) UI HTML rendering code in Scala (For the Spark Web UI if you care)

I would like to add a chart in it, using Javascript

```
class CustomPage(parent: CustomTab) extends WebUIPage("") {
    override def render(request: HttpServletRequest): Seq[Node] = {
    val content =
        <div>
        {
           <div id="custom"></div>

           //Javascript to render a chart goes here
        }
        </div>

        UIUtils.headerSparkPage("custom", content, parent, useDataTables = false)
    }
 }
```

I want to add some javascript code to add a chart ([like this code here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)), into the "content" variable

When I try to do it I end up having an ugly load of syntax errors -As I have no idea what I'm doing, TBH (mixing 2 worlds into one has never been my cup of tea)

What is the simplest approach and syntax to respect (to avoid brackets and single quotes getting in the way of the sala interpreter)